# Sending Local Storage data to Server

Tags: local-storage, httprequest

I want to use LocalStorage instead of cookies in situations where cookies are blocked. Problem is that the data is all for Server. Data to be sent across is not huge and adding it in query string is not the option because that again will impose limitation on the implementation. Is there any other efficient way to achieve the same ? Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: Send it as POST data.